# How to get looped input value specifically using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, loops

```
del_id = $('.button').attr('rel');
alert(del_id)
```

PHP:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
?>
    <div class="itemsin" >
    <span data-toggle="confirmation" rel="<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="button" id="rmlb">Click to Remove </span> 
    </div>
<?php
}

}

?>
```

I tried this but it's alerting only the first value out printed by loop please give me a suggestion

Comment: Where is the loop please post correct code

Comment: hey i edited now you can see please give me a suggestion i tried with above given jquery code but it is showing same value where ever i clicked

Comment: Please correct your code!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please post corrected and formatted code in future.

Here is what you need:

1. Collected all PHP output data in an JS array or object
2. Create a loop in JS to print all array values.
3. You need to be carefull with alerting each value because it will give a you a popup box for each array item and the annoying popup will never finish. I suggest outpoint them in console to see the result.

**Your JS Code:**

```
del_id  = document.querySelectorAll (".button");

for(var i = 0; i < del_id.length; i++){
    attrValue = $(this).attr('rel');
    console.log(attrValue);

    //You can also alert it if you wish to:

    //alert(attrValue);
}
```